# Running a .exe file using Java

Tags: java, runtime.exec

How to run an exe file using java code?The .exe file is already there. The plan is to write a Java code for running the same. Any tutorial or reference for the same?

Comment: What have the Googles told you?

Comment: Does that .exe needs STDIN/STDOUT? Is it a GUI app? Do you need to be notified when it terminates? Do you want it to continue running after your Java program terminates?

Answer (score 5):

Try the following code:

```
try 
{     
     Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime() ;     
     Process p = rt.exec("Program.exe") ;     
     InputStream in = p.getInputStream() ;    
     OutputStream out = p.getOutputStream ();     
     InputStream err = p.getErrorStream() ; 

     //do whatever you want 

     p.destroy() ; 
} 
catch(Exception exc) 
{
 /*handle exception*/
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to execute `exec()` method of `Runtime` that returns `Process` instance or use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class methods.

```
Process process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("file.exe");
```

Answer (score 0):

The quickest and easiest way is just to do as follows:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("yourapp.exe");
```

Also, see an alternative approach at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

There is an example there.  ProcessBuilder gives you a bit better control over the process and arguments and is probably a bit cleaner and more expressive, particularly if you need to supply arguments, but does result in a few more lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = rt.exec("javac");
```