# How can I run a .exe from my Java Program?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running a .exe file using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612921/running-a-exe-file-using-java)

**How can i run a .exe file from my java Program ?**
Is it possible ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please use the search (or google) before asking new questions; many have already been asked and answered.

Comment: Take a look at the `Runtime.exec`, as shown [here](http://www.ozzu.com/programming-forum/how-execute-exe-file-useing-java-program-t21081.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can use the following code.........

```
Runtime rt = Rintime.getRuntime() ;     
Process p => rt.exec("Program.exe") ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
try
{
    Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process p2 = r.exec("a.exe"); //absolute or relative path
}
catch(IOExeption ex)
{
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the privileges, you can run OS's commands with this:

```
String cmd = "c:/full/path/to/myCommand.exe";
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = run.exec(cmd);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class ExeRunner 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException 
    {
        ProcessBuilder proc = new ProcessBuilder("<your_exe>", "exe_args");
        proc.start();
    }
}
```

Refer: [ProcessBuilder vs Runtime.exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886829/processbuilder-vs-runtime-exec)