# NetBeans import exe for Java program

Tags: java, netbeans, import, exe, elevated-privileges

I'm using the http://jpassing.com/2007/12/08/launch-elevated-processes-from-the-command-line/ elevate program to give me administrator access to certain commands in my java program. I've imported the elevate.zip into my NetBeans library, but still cannot access the .exe itself via importing.

How can I import .exe files into NetBeans and use them inside java programs?

Note : when I export my program into a separate folder, the Elevate.exe works when called in the java program. However for programming purposes, I do need this to work in NetBeans.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running a .exe file using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612921/running-a-exe-file-using-java)

Comment: Can you clarify what the difference is then? It's not clear to me what you mean with "running inside of NetBeans" - how is that supposed to be different from executing the .exe from Java?

Comment: @JeenBroekstra NetBeans somehow doesn't recognize the .exe, but when I place the java files in a completely separate folder, then place the exe in that folder, its able to run.